# what is wrong with this rotation program in python?

Tags: python, rotation

context: (enigma machine)  What I am trying to do is get this bit of code to run so that the first wheel will rotate each time the sequences goes through the first wheel.

The problem is that i worked out how to do the rotation using a this sequences below from the internet yet it is not working when I change the variables around so that it can be auto-mated more. It comes up with error messages after the `if` function. I have checked through and changed the names of the variables to make them simpler and the spacing. And can't find out whats not working in the code. For is it that the rotate function can't use variables or what?

```
import collections

theinput=raw_input('enter letter')
x=0



w=collections.ww=([1,2,3,4,5])


if theinput == 'a':
    w.rotate(x)
    a = w[0]
    x= x+1
    w.rotate(x)
 print a
```

Thanks

Comment: @MarkByers there's nothing wrong in setting a value in a module (even if that's weird)

Comment: Pretty sure there's a typo on the line `w=collections.ww=([1,2,3,4,5])`... There's an extra "`=`".

Comment: Is there meant to be a space before "print a"?

Comment: what's your expected output here?your code is full of errors.

Comment: Oh right, he's assigning to it... strange.... I didn't notice that second `=`.

Comment: is there a rotate function in collections? I m still using python 2.x and  i know only about the collections.deque.rotate -method

Comment: The code looks broken - the assignment doesn't make sense (because `w.rotate() won't exist for a list object). There is no reference to "rotate" in [the collections module](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/afdb0e1a9dac/Lib/collections/__init__.py). I wouldn't read too much into it until the code is fixed.

Comment: Mark Byers yes there is thanks

Comment: Since when is there a `collections.ww`, anyway?

Comment: look below I explain that mistake Karl Knechtel (lack of knowledge of functions)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The container you probably want to use is [deque](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.deque), as far as I know there is no such variable as ww in collections module.

To put a bit of context, a deque is very similar to a list, but it is optimized in such a way that you can easily (efficiently) add and remove items at both ends, which is slightly more efficient that for built-in lists. Also deques provides some additional methods not found in lists, like rotate. While it's really easy to do the same things with lists combining basic operations, they are not optimized for these kind of things, while deques are. But for something as simple as simulation of an Enigma machine, sticking with lists wouldn't change performance much anyway.

I guess you are trying to do something like:

```
import collections
w = collections.deque([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
print "Deque state is ", w
print "First item in deque is", w[0]
w.rotate(1)
print "Deque state after rotation is ", w
print "First item in deque is", w[0]
```

This should print

```
Deque state is  deque([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
First item in deque is 1 Deque
state after rotation is  deque([5, 1, 2, 3, 4])
First item in deque is 5
```

Use negative numbers as arguments for rotate to turn the other way

Below is an alternative implementation using only built-in lists

```
w = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
print "List state is ", w
print "First item in list is", w[0]
x = 1 # x is rotation
w0 = w[:-x]
w = w[-x:]
w.extend(w0)
print "List state after rotation is ", w
print "First item in list is", w[0]
```

Comment: okay from the example i looked at 'deque' came up in front of the list so i thought it was a name/value. So thanks a lot!

Comment: Because `collections.deque` is the name of the class you are constructing, and the list is an argument you pass to its constructor (which is why there are also parentheses). You should learn more about how the language works first, honestly...